# Change onclick to onload for touch menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to the whole jQuery game but I found a great snippet that is just what I need, but I need the latter half to happen as the page loads, not when the button is clicked.

How do I make on page load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var touch = $('#touch-menu');
  var menu = $('.menu');

  $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 769 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
      menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [.load jquery](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What errors do you get from the console after following @Andrew Eisenberg answer?

Comment: If you view this site (http://parkoneproperties.com) on a mobile device and hit the menu button, it slides down.

Basically, I'm trying to get rid of having to touch the menu button, and have the menu slide down when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by 'the latter half'. I assume that you mean this piece:

```
$(touch).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menu.slideToggle();
});
```

To do what you want, simple move `menu.slideToggle();` out of the click handler. In fact, you should remove the click handler completely and place `menu.slideToggle();` just under the menu declaration.

Comment: Excuse the latter half part.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Excuse the latter half part. 

I did what you suggested but, not working. 

Wouldn't be something like "$(window).load(function()"?

Comment: `$(window).load()` may not work since it is called before the DOM is completely ready and `#menu` may not be available yet. What exactly are you trying to do and what is not working for you?

Comment: If you view this site (http://parkoneproperties.com) on a mobile device and hit the menu button, it slides down.

Basically, I'm trying to get rid of having to touch the menu button, and have the menu slide down when the page loads.

Comment: So, the problem that I am seeing on your page is that you have included `main.js` before `jquery.js`. You need to swap the order. You can't use the `$` variable until jquery has been loaded.